# separate elements with a comma in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, typescript

Here is the input:

```
scheduleInput = { schedulefor: "weekdays" , weekdays: "" , days:""}
```

This is the TS file

```
onChangeCheckWeek(week:any ,  isChecked: boolean) {
  if (isChecked) {
    this.checkAll = false;
    this.scheduleInput.weekdays= this.scheduleInput.weekdays + week; 
    // The weekdays are stored in this.scheduleInput.weekdays and week is having the newly slected checkbox
    week.split(/[ ,]+/);
  } else {
    this.checkAll = false;
    this.selectAllWeekDays= false;
  }
}
```

This is the HTML:

```html
<div class="Schedule container-fluid" *ngIf="scheduleInput.schedulefor == 'weekdays'">
  <div class="my-info-1 row weekday">
    <h4 class="mgtop-15">
      Weekly :
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0 warning">
      <input type="checkbox" id="rem"  class="custom-control-input" [checked]="checkAll" (change)="onChangeCheckAll($event.target.checked)" [(ngModel)]="selectAllWeekDays">
      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
      Select All
    </label></div>
    <div class="row mgtop-5">
     <div class="col-sm-4 ">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
          <input type="checkbox" id="rem"  class="custom-control-input"  [checked]="checkAllWeek" (change)="onChangeCheckWeek('Monday', $event.target.checked)"   [value]="Monday" >
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
          <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
          Monday
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
          <input type="checkbox" id="rem"  class="custom-control-input" [checked]="checkAllWeek" (change)="onChangeCheckWeek('Tuesday', $event.target.checked)" [value]="Tuesday"  >
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
          <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
          Tuesday
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4  ">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
          <input type="checkbox" id="rem"  class="custom-control-input" [checked]="checkAllWeek" (change)="onChangeCheckWeek('Wednesday', $event.target.checked)" [value]="Wednesday">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
          <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
          Wednesday
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mgtop-5">
      <div class="col-sm-4  ">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
          <input type="checkbox" id="rem"  class="custom-control-input" [checked]="checkAllWeek" (change)="onChangeCheckWeek('Thursday', $event.target.checked)" [value]="Thursday">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
          <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
          Thursday
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4  ">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
         <input type="checkbox" id="rem"  class="custom-control-input" [checked]="checkAllWeek" (change)="onChangeCheckWeek('Friday', $event.target.checked)" [value]="Friday" >
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
          <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
          Friday
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 ">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
          <input type="checkbox" id="rem"  class="custom-control-input"  [checked]="checkAllWeek" (change)="onChangeCheckWeek('Saturday', $event.target.checked)"  [value]="Saturday">
            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
            Saturday
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row mgtop-5">
        <div class="col-sm-4 ">
          <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
            <input type="checkbox" id="rem"  class="custom-control-input"  [checked]="checkAllWeek" (change)="onChangeCheckWeek('Sunday' , $event.target.checked)"  [value]="Sunday">
            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
            Sunday
          </label>
        </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 mgtop-5"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When I check the weekdays in the console after checking the checkboxes which is getting stored in week it is showing as;

```
MondayTuesdayWednesday....
```

I want it to be displayed as

```
Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday...
```

I also want it to be displayed in the same order even if Saturday is selected first and the other week days are selected after that. Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Change `this.scheduleInput.weekdays` to an array instead of a string. Then you can simply `push()` the new entries in to it and `join()` them when displaying to get them as a comma separated string

Comment: You should really just post a relevant fraction of your code instead of a whole wall of code. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Quote: "Introduce the problem before you post any code", "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem".

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegEx `/[A-Z][a-z]+/g` on your current result to split on uppercase letter like the following:

```js
var days = 'MondayTuesdayWednesday'
days = days.match(/[A-Z][a-z]+/g).join(', ');
console.log(days);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick:

```
var week="MondayTuesdayWednesdayThursdayFridaySaturdaySunday";
var str=week.match(/[A-Z]*[^A-Z]+/g).join(', ');
console.log(str);
```